# Transform query into usable data to create (pivot)graph

Tags: graph, pivot-table, powerquery

I have a large dataset uploaded as a query in PowerQuery. I am looking to create one or multiple graphs but face some difficulties.

I have the following columns:

- YYYY-MM
- Sales channel
- BU
  and another 5 columns with numeric values.

I would like to show a graph (with slicers) which shows "YYYY-MM" on the horizontal axis (that's easy). But I would also like to the show the 5 value columns, depending on the slicer for one or more sales channels en one or more BU's.

In order to do that, do I need to create new value colums for each sales channel and/or BU (and if yes, is there an easy way to do that?) or is there another (easier) way?

Many thanks,

Tim

I've tried shifting legends and axis but I do not get the required result.